# Sort JSON response by data in cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a table named products

```
ProudctID   ProductName
1           A
2           B
3           C
4           D
```

I want to sort the products using javascript. SO what i did is...

```
var visits= [
   { 'ProudctID' : 4 }
];
$.cookie("visit", JSON.stringify(visits));
```

on each product view i am doing this

```
var visits= $.parseJSON($.cookie("visits");)
visits.push(
    { 'ProudctID' : 1}
);
$.cookie("visit", JSON.stringify(visits));
```

I have JSON result of all products, so how can i sort Product by ProductID based on what is storred in the cookie..

Answer (score 2):

Your `visits` variable refers to an array. Two options for you:

1. Arrays have this handy [`sort` method](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11). ;-) It accepts a function to use to compare the items in the array. So just use `sort` after adding your item.
2. Instead of `push`, loop through the array to find the correct location for the new entry, then use [`splice`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.12) to put it in the correct place. (Like an insertion sort does.) Then the array is always sorted.

Because arrays are a first-class JSON concept, the order will be maintained when being stingified and revived.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest would be not to store objects and just store array of the ID's themselves.

```
var visits= $.parseJSON($.cookie("visits");)
visits.push( /* value */);
visits.sort();
$.cookie("visit", JSON.stringify(visits));
```